# bucardo master-master репликация данных

Tags: postgresql, synchronized

Возникла необходимость настроить репликацию для Postgresql 9.

Для решения задачи выбрал Bucardo. Настройку сделал по [описанию](http://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/65312/). Синхронизация выбрана MASTER-MASTER, и работает отлично.

Вопрос: возможно сделать полный перенос/синхронизацию данных на второй сервер (mydb_node2)? То есть:

1. Сделан дамп mydb (было сделано несколько дампов, первый - база с наполнением, второй - только таблицы базы без наполнения).
2. Перенесён дамп на второй сервер и восстановлена mydb.
3. Настроил синхронизации (проверил работоспособность - работает).
4. Но, пока делались предыдущие этапы - прошло пару минут, и в основной БД
   появились новый записи (около 100 записей в секунду). Как
   синхронизировать данный, который появились в этот промежуток
   времени?

Как возможно реализовать переливку с сервера на сервер, чтобы БД были одинаковы, без останова Posgresql?

Comment: Не видел никого, кто бы успешно в продакшене использовал мастер-мастер репликацию. Какая у вас стоит собственно задача?

Comment: к одной базе подключено несколько проектов, то есть
на node_1 крутится projekt1, project2, project3
на node_2 крутится project3, project4